# AWK take some data input from file and set as variable in output

Tags: parsing, awk, printf

I have some data in file and need to print in output some format to the data in print.

Example content to parse:

```
012231-33339411.sxz.ree.fg*-* 
U2FsdGVkX1+1pfXeR/h4u6P/BrItX75L0wHVIka4yA6tqS9a5CFUWvLu1AB4x2m8NpmJ>fyoXdADqlWDiGWi6Pw1a8NgNDbdTOlMtGBz4FCi8n97UdVQX9f0a2u9d5l7lOCxVDDzd>wJXbi9x4O+Dmo/lm9DbWAjBGKwWu0tTQxsU2TIpqv
FhUZmGd3E6vN+puPXz4yXeVQhMfQ+K8OpSM2ZuTpKCtDgm0SdUDyFnalA4lxHaFZqh+E>3+9JgHK7/KiiZmIJshUmqrwnkX0yKihCcOXCzaFITiByxBM/7PGeJo0IBAjyKI/GflgQ>8GsIWWRkCJnz2OMiYKr8uOMOAfTHnW57Dq+orDG1p
012236-33349111.sxz.ree.fg*-*
bCRIVArOSClIWrZz6KciBFT2iPjqsS/qMRSBYinBzpDmESj8kZHoGQ46BMq+LgHJiY5P>7yygNxCkEv25GKGViKTX1X6KSSLZ+RVNEts4N7jzVLoufZ+X/TAv2Ib7pnnEj7h4rWDn>y7KP1XrTynItaas5z5fpFt2zUHFNElvNmyrjbFZVp
DUsnWWDuvemWUr5YwOLxeRCnwTvfw71gwGEVeBzIJq4TsZb2/G8j9vpb/L7KNybsyQNN>DlOTMW5CHzd5otyYaNBcYo9V/4ky63q2vZMzQDWtCwVPaTKREPUqPLRKea3VkQnnsUic>/iBe+6Sv5GYl+XPGbIjWbTJWLQmc1kv8LXPyvUmTm
cUVypKp9fDlyFUkOkEVAxW8dMxHJ0c83BPw37GkCvsR9itkzO0FpX0Zn+OvRQRkUCyzr>dgijhcH
```

I need some way to take in Awk the first variable from begin to "-"
Example:

```
variable1=012231
```

and

```
variable1=012236
```

Variable 2 the 4 digits after the - character
Example:

```
Variable2=3333
```

and

```
variable2=3334
```

Variable 3 the 2 digits after the 4 digits of variable2
Example:

```
variable3=94
```

and

```
variable3=91
```

Variable 4 as the text before the newline
Example:

```
variable4=U2FsdGVkX1+1pfXeR/h4u6P/BrItX75L0wHVIka4yA6tqS9a5CFUWvLu1AB4x2m8NpmJ>fyoXdADqlWDiGWi6Pw1a8NgNDbdTOlMtGBz4FCi8n97UdVQX9f0a2u9d5l7lOCxVDDzd>wJXbi9x4O+Dmo/lm9DbWAjBGKwWu0tTQxsU2TIpqv
FhUZmGd3E6vN+puPXz4yXeVQhMfQ+K8OpSM2ZuTpKCtDgm0SdUDyFnalA4lxHaFZqh+E>3+9JgHK7/KiiZmIJshUmqrwnkX0yKihCcOXCzaFITiByxBM/7PGeJo0IBAjyKI/GflgQ>8GsIWWRkCJnz2OMiYKr8uOMOAfTHnW57Dq+orDG1p
```

and

```
variable4=bCRIVArOSClIWrZz6KciBFT2iPjqsS/qMRSBYinBzpDmESj8kZHoGQ46BMq+LgHJiY5P>7yygNxCkEv25GKGViKTX1X6KSSLZ+RVNEts4N7jzVLoufZ+X/TAv2Ib7pnnEj7h4rWDn>y7KP1XrTynItaas5z5fpFt2zUHFNElvNmyrjbFZVp
DUsnWWDuvemWUr5YwOLxeRCnwTvfw71gwGEVeBzIJq4TsZb2/G8j9vpb/L7KNybsyQNN>DlOTMW5CHzd5otyYaNBcYo9V/4ky63q2vZMzQDWtCwVPaTKREPUqPLRKea3VkQnnsUic>/iBe+6Sv5GYl+XPGbIjWbTJWLQmc1kv8LXPyvUmTm
cUVypKp9fDlyFUkOkEVAxW8dMxHJ0c83BPw37GkCvsR9itkzO0FpX0Zn+OvRQRkUCyzr>dgijhcH
```

Example print expected in output:

```
'012231' '3333' '94' 'U2FsdGVkX1+1pfXeR/h4u6P/BrItX75L0wHVIka4yA6tqS9a5CFUWvLu1AB4x2m8NpmJ>fyoXdADqlWDiGWi6Pw1a8NgNDbdTOlMtGBz4FCi8n97UdVQX9f0a2u9d5l7lOCxVDDzd>wJXbi9x4O+Dmo/lm9DbWAjBGKwWu0tTQxsU2TIpqv
FhUZmGd3E6vN+puPXz4yXeVQhMfQ+K8OpSM2ZuTpKCtDgm0SdUDyFnalA4lxHaFZqh+E>3+9JgHK7/KiiZmIJshUmqrwnkX0yKihCcOXCzaFITiByxBM/7PGeJo0IBAjyKI/GflgQ>8GsIWWRkCJnz2OMiYKr8uOMOAfTHnW57Dq+orDG1p'
'012236' '3334' '91' 'bCRIVArOSClIWrZz6KciBFT2iPjqsS/qMRSBYinBzpDmESj8kZHoGQ46BMq+LgHJiY5P>7yygNxCkEv25GKGViKTX1X6KSSLZ+RVNEts4N7jzVLoufZ+X/TAv2Ib7pnnEj7h4rWDn>y7KP1XrTynItaas5z5fpFt2zUHFNElvNmyrjbFZVp
DUsnWWDuvemWUr5YwOLxeRCnwTvfw71gwGEVeBzIJq4TsZb2/G8j9vpb/L7KNybsyQNN>DlOTMW5CHzd5otyYaNBcYo9V/4ky63q2vZMzQDWtCwVPaTKREPUqPLRKea3VkQnnsUic>/iBe+6Sv5GYl+XPGbIjWbTJWLQmc1kv8LXPyvUmTm
cUVypKp9fDlyFUkOkEVAxW8dMxHJ0c83BPw37GkCvsR9itkzO0FpX0Zn+OvRQRkUCyzr>dgijhcH'
```

Haved tested the following code with result of print selecting by number of record and counting the fixed width of the field, without care the format or shape of the content.

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="6 1 4 2 2 15" 'NR==1{print $1" "$3" "$4}NR==2{print}NR==3{print $1" "$3" "$4}NR==4{print}' file
```

But it`s a large file with variable lenght of number of records in the large string so the equal will not work for this case I will need catch this string to a variable to print it later in the output as field in all the sequences of show this field.

Could help me with some code to parse the input and print the output as close to the need, please explain how to take the positions in the input.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, try [reading the documentation for Gnu awk's string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) and see if you can figure out which to use.

Comment: The wanted way to know is the way to catch the variables in the strings to have a serial output as expected.

Comment: @rici thank by your comment I haved visited and looked at http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ so many information about how to work with strings but it`s focused to build regexps in the examples and didn`t cover the way to take variables in specific desired text in the input, or isn`t clear to me.

Comment: I think your posted expected output is wrong as it's missing some `>` characters that are present in your input (e.g. `pmJ>fyo` in the input becomes `pmJfyo` in  the output) and adds some `>`s to the output that aren't present in the input (e.g. `QX9f0a` in the input becomes `QX9>f0a` in the output). Please check that and [edit] your question to fix it if it's wrong or explain how to get that output from that input otherwise.

Comment: @Ed Morton thank by your quick response I wish to vote your response because you deserve it but don`t have the reputation to do it. You think right the text of variable4 was different in the question, maybe the editor of stackov.  The same string in the input and output was expected means your code are working fine. Maybe can you explain me the function how it works, how can you isolate from the others vars the number 4. I´m insterested in learn.  Thanks again!

Comment: The answer was closed, I thought was clear in the format of the question, I don`t know how to open it again, it`s very good to know how catch variables from desired input and useful.

Comment: I was edited the question to match the input and variable output, because the text was changed by editor of StackOverflow or my personal editor. Thank you all.

Comment: @user_testing_uxy I actually think my script is very clear and simple and you'd learn a lot more about awk by trying to understand it (possibly looking at the man page to find out what `split()`, `NR`, `delete`, and `next` do, and/or adding print statements to dump values to see how they're being populated) so please try to understand it yourself and then ask specific questions about any parts of it that aren't clear afterwards.

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes I will try to match this knowledge with your code and the needs of the question,, I will test some cases and try to change the printf to other ways of output. I really appreciate your comments/time and votes, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
split($0,f,"-") > 1 {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
        delete var
    }
    var[1] = f[1]
    var[2] = substr(f[2],1,4)
    var[3] = substr(f[2],5,2)
    next
}
{ var[4] = var[4] $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
        printf "\047%s\047%s", var[i], (i<4 ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
'012231' '3333' '94' 'U2FsdGVkX1+1pfXeR/h4u6P/BrItX75L0wHVIka4yA6tqS9a5CFUWvLu1AB4x2m8NpmJ>fyoXdADqlWDiGWi6Pw1a8NgNDbdTOlMtGBz4FCi8n97UdVQX9f0a2u9d5l7lOCxVDDzd>wJXbi9x4O+Dmo/lm9DbWAjBGKwWu0tTQxsU2TIpqvFhUZmGd3E6vN+puPXz4yXeVQhMfQ+K8OpSM2ZuTpKCtDgm0SdUDyFnalA4lxHaFZqh+E>3+9JgHK7/KiiZmIJshUmqrwnkX0yKihCcOXCzaFITiByxBM/7PGeJo0IBAjyKI/GflgQ>8GsIWWRkCJnz2OMiYKr8uOMOAfTHnW57Dq+orDG1p'
'012236' '3334' '91' 'bCRIVArOSClIWrZz6KciBFT2iPjqsS/qMRSBYinBzpDmESj8kZHoGQ46BMq+LgHJiY5P>7yygNxCkEv25GKGViKTX1X6KSSLZ+RVNEts4N7jzVLoufZ+X/TAv2Ib7pnnEj7h4rWDn>y7KP1XrTynItaas5z5fpFt2zUHFNElvNmyrjbFZVpDUsnWWDuvemWUr5YwOLxeRCnwTvfw71gwGEVeBzIJq4TsZb2/G8j9vpb/L7KNybsyQNN>DlOTMW5CHzd5otyYaNBcYo9V/4ky63q2vZMzQDWtCwVPaTKREPUqPLRKea3VkQnnsUic>/iBe+6Sv5GYl+XPGbIjWbTJWLQmc1kv8LXPyvUmTmcUVypKp9fDlyFUkOkEVAxW8dMxHJ0c83BPw37GkCvsR9itkzO0FpX0Zn+OvRQRkUCyzr>dgijhcH'
```